# Spring Rest Controller vs Camel rest servlet in micro services --- What's the difference , is camel have any other adv?

Tags: spring, apache-camel

In my previous application, i have exposed rest api using spring rest controllers.

Now i'm going to work in spring boot microservice where they have used , camel rest services.

Is there any adv of camel rest compared with spring rest?

Answer (score 0):

> Apache Camel offers a REST styled DSL which can be used with Java or
>   XML. The intention is to allow end users to define REST services using
>   a REST style with verbs such as get, post, delete etc.

Source https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/rest-dsl.html

The idea of Camel REST endpoints is to start e Camel Route with a REST Call.

If you don't need Camel Routes it doesn't make sense to use Camel REST.

On the other side Spring MVC provides the ability to define REST APIs that will use other Spring Components to fullfil use case.

Comment: Thanks for your response.. Still i didn't get

Comment: If you must use Camel use Camel REST. In all other cases don't use Camel.

Comment: Use whatever you want. If you want or are more faimilar with Spring Rest code and want to tie you to spring then use that. Camel is just a library and only use what you really want from Camel. The Rest DSL in Camel is agnostic and dont require spring or anything like that and its goal is as Simon says above. To define REST services using a Camel route like style.

Comment: So what you can do is to use spring rest controller and then from this controller call into Camel when needed. There is such example in the Camel in Action 2nd ed book.

Comment: I think that what @SimonMartinelli tried to say is that if you wont use Camel Routes in your application, there's no need to use Camel Rest, since Camel Rest, in simple words, is the way to trigger Camel Routes using REST communication. PS: Camel Routes != Camel Rest