# Why using Apache Camel rest DSL rather than spring boot rest controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, apache-camel

I just searched many topics of camel, many of them mentioned that Camel provided the rest api support, but I don't know why it provides it ? As it can integrate many frameworks , for example spring, and springmvc/springboot also provide the rest ability.

As a beginner for camel, the first question of mine is just : what's the benifit / adv of apache camel for rest ? why use camel rest route api rather than springboot restcontroller ? At least, you can see that springboot rest controller can provide the restful api with explicit design/implementations, readable annotations and well integrated with spring validation, swagger UI , etc.

Another question from me, if need to use apache camel, can we use spring rest controller for rest api and camel for other parts ? Or it's not suggested to do things in this way ?

Comment: There's a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59610105/spring-rest-controller-vs-camel-rest-servlet-in-micro-services-whats-the-di/,   but I cannot get expected answer from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, Camel is an **integration library that can be used in many environments**. It can be used standalone, with Spring Framework, in Apache Karaf etc. So this is a first point:

> When Camel is used without Spring, it is worth nothing that Spring has excellent REST support.

Camel excels with its more than 200 components. It **supports mainly everything** (protocols, data formats etc) that is used out there and it **abstracts most of the annoying transport level code away** from you. You simply use a DSL to build integrations between different types of endpoints.

```
rest("/orders")
    .post()
    .to("activemq:queue:myQueue")
```

This is a 3 line Camel integration that receives REST calls from clients (POST) and sends the received data to a JMS message queue. Here we got the second point:

> Even if Spring is available, Camel must provide REST support in the Camel DSL to allow REST integrations with other endpoints

And yes, you can of course use the Spring Framework to build a REST service and then call this REST service from a Camel Route. But what is not possible, is using this Spring REST service as a Consumer of a Camel Route (the 3-line example above).

Comment: Got it ! Much appreciated! You solved a problem that has puzzled me for a long time! :)

Answer (score 1):

Burki's response is great. In my opinion, it does worth adding two additional points.

- if you like the way Spring lets you implement your service, you can still benefit from both worlds and integrate your `@RestController` with your Camel Route by using an istance of `FluentProducerTemplate`.
- if you build your service with Camel from the beginning, including the Rest DSL you can take advantage of Camel's error handling implementation (which is very great, imho) from the earliest stages of your application

More often than not, using Camel is not just a matter of having fewer lines of code. Camel brings you the power of a complete lightweight framework, more than 280 components, type and dataformat converters, not to mention EIPs, therefore REST DSL can be considered just as the front door :)